# KeyEvent.getKeyText() is returning special characters in OSX (e.g. for 'VK_ENTER') but not on Windows XP, any solution?

Tags: java, text, awt, keyevent

I am using KeyEvents and

```
KeyEvent.getKeyText(KeyEvent.VK_...)
```

in order to get the text corresponding to the KeyEvent.

In OSX (Lion) when I request the text for a special key, like TAB or ENTER (KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) I get the corresponding symbol (e.g. for Enter, I get the curved arrow). The same in a Windows XP system gives me the key name (e.g. "Enter") instead of the symbol.

Is there a solution to get the special characters in XP, too?

Comment: Aren't you taking your job - a bit - too seriously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAC have different implementation:

> These were changed intentionally to provide the proper symbols for
>   menu shortcuts in Swing for in-window menu bars. Instead of using the
>   word "Meta" or "Command" we actually now return the unicode symbol
>   that the system menu bar shows.

In that case, you can use the constants for that keys, `VK_ENTER`, e.g.

```
if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_KP_DOWN) {}
```

Or you can map the keys to its string names with `Map`

```
map.put(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, '\u21b5'); \\ ↵
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll stick with the map ;)